# How to use a ZVS voltage booster to create the Jacob's ladder?

Tags: voltage, high-voltage, zvs

How to use this ZVS voltage booster to create the Jacob's ladder?

I bought it from the internet (eBay):

> [image]
>
> #### Description:
>
> This is the design of a flyback foreigner drive circuit
>   for driving the ignition coil, as do zero-voltage switching (Zero
>   Voltage Switching) and the majority of domestic fans are referred to
>   as "ZVS". Because power, low heat, simple and reliable are widely used
>   in driving enthusiasts spark gap Tesla coil (SGTC) and Jacobs ladder,
>   Marx generators and other devices.
>
> The ZVS driver circuit are of high quality components, high
>   reliability, strong power. Input 12-24V / 10A DC. High voltage DC
>   output voltage is about 800 times the input voltage.
>
> Product parameters: Size: 74mm * 77mm Input voltage: DC 12V-30V Power
>   requirements: less than 12V≥5A 15V above ≥15A Operating Frequency:
>   30kHz-50kHz adaptive Secondary parameters: 5T + 5T
>
> Voltage: Input voltage and current output voltage with maximum power
>   12V / 5A approximately 10000V 60W 24V / 10A about 20000V 200W
>
> This element driving circuit used are new and original, never cut
>   corners. ... The board is double-sided, using the entire back surface
>   of the resonant circuit traces, resistance is small, less heat, good
>   heat dissipation, high-performance is not a single panel can compare.

I followed the documentation to use two copper rods. The spark does appear, but it won't go up, but remains on the bottom side.

```
*   *
|   |
 | |
 |x|
+---+
+---+
```

The `x` is the spark. After it appears, if I move one of the rods, it jumps on the top, but I would like to not move the rod and make the spark jump.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please don't link to eBay pages. Once that item is removed your question becomes useless to anyone else. Link to a datasheet instead and post relevant details in your question so that the information is here forever we don't all have to look it up.

Comment: @Transistor Good point. I just thought it's easier to check it out directly there. I updated my question.

Comment: @Transistor Umm, and can you help with an answer?

Comment: A Jacob's ladder is arranged with the two rods set in nearly vertical orientation, not unlike the "rabbit ears" on old TV sets. The bottom of each rod might be separated by a small gap -- about as much as you can manage without extinguishing the spark -- and the top of each rod separated by still more distance. They should be closer together at the bottom and wider at the top. The spark arcs, heats the air, the hot ionized air rises, and the arc follows it upward. Is that what you have arranged already? It's not clear to me, if so. Too close at the bottom and the spark might just stay there.

Comment: @jonk Yes, I tried that but if the gap on the bottom is not small enough, the spark doesn't appear. If the gap is small, so the spark appears, probably it's not hot enough to make it go up. Should the rods be made of a specific metal? When it's too close, the spark doesn't go up because it's not powerful enough to heat enough air. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: I wish I could say for sure. I've never had any problems making a jacob's ladder work before. I've used coat hangers that weren't even all that straight before. I just adjust things until they go. I think I always have some tinkering to do. But I don't remember it ever taking long to work out. I suppose it's possible that you aren't heating the air enough. Or that your angle of separation between them as they rise is too rapid.